# DataContractJSONSerializer nested DataContract objects containing lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Background: We are using an attribute that changes the output of the response to a JSON object when certain headers are passed. Another attribute returns XML when the appropriate accept header is passed. If the accept header is missing or "html", a test page is returned.

I need to be able to serialize an object structure like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseModel
{
   [DataMember]
   public bool Success { get; set;}

   [DataMember]
   public dynamic Data { get; set; } //I have tried "Object" as well

   [DataMember]
   public ApiErrorModel Error { get; set; } 

}

//for reference
[DataContract]
public class ApiErrorModel 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I'm having is while I haven't been able to test any error states yet, when it goes to serialize a structure like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class DatabaseModel
{
   [DataMember]
   List<Database> Database { get; set; }
   //snip implementation
}

[DataContract]
public class Database
{
   [DataMember]
   [Required]
   public string DatabaseName { get; set; }

   [DataMember]
   List<Guid> APITokens { get; set; }

   //snip other fields..., Guids and strings...
}
```

It fails, giving me the error:

Type '[namespace].Api.Business.Web.Models.DatabaseModel' with data contract name 'DatabaseModel:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/[namespace].Api.Business.Web.Models' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

I have researched using a DataContractResolver, but I can't seem to get it to work with the JSON version of it. It may be easier to switch to JSON.NET or JavaScriptSerializer serializer, but it needs to work for XML as well (This might be a JSON-specific issue). I'm wondering if there's a way to fix this without adding every type of list I'm going to use to the serialization method list of known types.

Comment: Is `APITokenId` a `DataContract`?

Comment: Actually, it's just a List<Guid>, I was unable to efficiently copy and paste between the two computers.

Comment: What is your service contract that uses these data contracts? Can you post the interface/class definition and also some method signatures? You may have to use the `KnownType` attribute.

Comment: It's just an ASP.NET MVC Action Result with an attribute that serializes the output stream if accept/json is passed in.

Comment: We ended up (quite awhile ago) using JSON.NET. It works 100% perfectly. We don't need XML _right now_ so we'll leave it broken for now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JSON.NET is basically the way to go. It seems the DataContractJsonSerializer isn't up for the task.